# Set value to @Html.Editor MVC

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, view

Can somebody help me here, I have the following:

```
@Html.Editor("entities[" + @k + "].Amount", entity.Amount)
```

I would like the Editor to display the amount in the text-field. I have tried the following:

```
@Html.Editor("entities[" + @k + "].Amount", entity.Amount, new { @Value = "45"}) <text> m</text>
```

And I got the following error:

```
CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<ProjectName.Order>' does not contain a definition for 'Editor' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.Editor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, object)' has some invalid arguments.
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used TextBox instead and it worked fine =)

```
@Html.TextBox("entities[" + @k + "].Amount", entity.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "text-field" } })
```